# Add Text box value on key press event and assign to second text box with sum

Tags: jquery

i have two text boxes in my form in first text box value is changed randomly on every key press event.i want to add all values which have changed and assign to as well into second text as well at the time of key press event.

like:
first call:
first text value:25
second text value:25
second call:
first text box:45
second text value should be:25+45=70

Comment: please show some effort and code

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic code that will do what you've described :

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yhwk1q1f/)**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="box_1" class="box"></div><p></p>
<div id="box_2" class="box"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.box
{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
var val1 = 0;
var val2 = 0;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).keypress(function(e)
  {
    val1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    val2 += val1;
    $("#box_1").text(val1);
    $("#box_2").text(val2);
    })
});
```

I hope this helps. :)

Cheers,
Fjpackard.

Comment: it is not adding values into second variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what the issue is.  Could you please try to explain in more detail, and post the error here if there is one ?  Also, are you currently using the JSFiddle link I provided, or are you running the code locally ?